# Find the most frequently occurring item in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making a library database and I am having a problem in one place. I need to find most popular borrowed book. I have these tables.

```
--Books--          --BookReader--             --Readers--
book_id              book_id                    reader_id
                 reader_id
```

FOR EXAMPLE DATA IN TABLE BookReader;

```
----BookReader---
reader_id book_id
1        |    2
1        |    3
3        |    2
```

I think I need to count every book_id in BookReader which is equal(2, 3 and so on) and than find that max number.

I can't write the SQL query to find most popular borrowed `book(bookId)`?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? Perhaps you should study the material recommended by your instructor.

Comment: yes it is study, i quess u are right :)

Comment: @Donatas Vileita see this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee484/19 more common SQL querys what you can study.. HAVING works like an filter after GROUP BY..  good luck

Answer (score 1):

```
select book_id,count(book_id) as buys
from BookReader
group by book_id
order by buys desc
limit 1
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee484/10)